# Drag and drop game in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a drag and drop game. The user should choose the correct shape to drag and drop onto the box. I followed this tutorial [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implementing-drag-and-drop-functionality/) When the user has dragged the wrong object, it won't be displaying **WRONG ANSWER** yet. The warning should displayed when he drops it onto the basket object. I have tried this:

```
TextView objBasket, tx, timer;
int trial = 0;
TextView obj[] = new TextView[4];
int[] images = {
        R.drawable.stage4_object1, // Correct Answer a
        R.drawable.stage4_object2,
        R.drawable.stage4_object3,
        R.drawable.stage4_object4
};

List<TextView> iv = new ArrayList<TextView>();
String[] tagList = {"a","b","c","d"}; 


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.stage4_1);

    // I created a custom countdown timer c/o Say
            counter = new MyCount(30000,1000);
            counter.start();

    initControls();

    getCorrectObject();

}

private void getCorrectObject() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int arr : images){
        objects.add(arr);
    }

    // Shuffle the collection
    Collections.shuffle(objects);

    iv.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object1));
    iv.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object2));
    iv.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object3));
    iv.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStage4_object4));

    Collections.shuffle(iv);

    iv.get(0).setBackgroundResource(images[0]); 
    iv.get(1).setBackgroundResource(images[1]); 
    iv.get(2).setBackgroundResource(images[2]); 
    iv.get(3).setBackgroundResource(images[3]); 

    iv.get(0).setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener()); 
    iv.get(1).setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener()); 
    iv.get(2).setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());
    iv.get(3).setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener());

    for (int i = 0; i < tagList.length; i++) { 
        iv.get(i).setTag(tagList[i]); 
    } 

}

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //setup drag
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

            //start dragging the item touched
            v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub               
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            //handle the dragged view being dropped over a drop view
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();

            //stop displaying the view where it was before it was dragged
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            //view dragged item is being dropped on
            TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;

            //view being dragged and dropped
            TextView dropped = (TextView) view;

            for (int i = 0; i < iv.size(); i++) { 
                final int k = i; 

                    String tmp = "a"; 

                    if (tmp.equals(iv.get(k).getTag())) {   
                        Log.i("result","CORRECT ANSWER: "+ tmp); 
                        goToNextQuestion();
                    } else { 
                        Log.i("result","WRONG ANSWER: "+ iv.get(k).getTag());
                        trial++;
                        guessedWrong();
                        playWrongSound();
                    } 

            }


            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            //no action necessary
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
        return true;
    }


}
```

But it won't go to the next question whenever I choose the correct object. What am I missing in here? I really need help to finish this game. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I see two problems with your program.

You created your ChoiceDragListener class but you didn't register it with any of those items you wish to drag around. This appears to be missing from your getCorrectObject method.

```
iv.get(0).setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener ()); 
iv.get(1).setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener ()); 
iv.get(2).setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener ());
iv.get(3).setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener ());
```

The other problem that I see is with your ACTION_DROP case from your switch statement. First you get the TextView that the user has dropped but then you begin to cycle through all of your text views anyways. The code inside the ACTION_DROP case should look more like:

```
View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
TextView dropTarget = (TextView) v;
TextView dropped = (TextView) view;
String temp = "a";
if(temp.equals(view.getTag()){
   goToNextQuestion();
}else{
   guessedWrong()
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but when I tried to do this, the wrong object that was chosen never goes back to its default position. Can you help me point out how to do that?

Comment: This can be a little bit more complex. I would declare an x and y int variable along with you trial variable. In your onTouch method set x = v.getLeft() and y = v.getTop(). This gets the objects x and y positions. Then when your gamer guesses wrong you could say view.setX(x) and view.setY(y); This should reset the position back to where it was when the player initially touched the text view.

Comment: Thanks, but I managed to do it, using view.setVisibility(VISIBLE);